# Run function after button events

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button, pageload

Buttons in asp.net automatically refresh the page. Before the button events are called, the default Page_Load function is called (I think).

I'm looking for a way to call a function after all of the button events are called.

**EDIT**

I want to always call the function, even if there's no button pressed. So putting the function in the button event doesn't work.

**Creating a button**

```
ImageButton enc2Button = Hardwarerecorders.DeviceManager.getEncStatusImage(d, "res/", false);
```

**This is the click event**

```
enc2Button.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(startEnc2);
```

**Button event function**

```
void startEnc2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton)sender;
    int arrayIndex = Int32.Parse(button.Attributes["index"]);
    Hardwarerecorders.DeviceManager.startEnc((Hardwarerecorders.Device)devices[arrayIndex], false);
}
```

Comment: If you don't add some code and improve the quality of this post it's very difficult to help you

Comment: Are you talking about javascript function? Or a code behind?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri I'm talking about a C# function

Comment: If you want to call any c# function after buttons click event, you can call that function at last line of your button click event method. I guess, you have idea about doing this. Please post some code if you are referring something else.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri See the edit

Comment: You  want to call function always without whether button is clicked or not? I didn't understand. If you want to call function whenever any postback occurs, please call that function in page load event.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri The page load event is called before the button events (I think).. I want to call the function after the button events, not before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105667/discussion-between-m-zeinstra-and-piyush-khatri).

Answer (score 1):

Just override the OnPreRender-Method. It's called after Control-Events.

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
       base.OnPreRender(e);
       //Your stuff
    }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105667/discussion-between-m-zeinstra-and-piyush-khatri

Answer (score 0):

Use `Response.redirect("index.aspx");`

as the last line within your button, this re-direct the page to `index.aspx`, instead of using `index.aspx` use the name of the file on which your button is placed on, the page will refresh and it'll work as intended.

so as follows -

```
    void startEnc2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton)sender;
        int arrayIndex = Int32.Parse(button.Attributes["index"]);
        Hardwarerecorders.DeviceManager.startEnc((Hardwarerecorders.Device)devices[arrayIndex], false);
        Response.redirect("index.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call any function after button event by calling simple that function in the end. It would be good if you post you code here in order to understand the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you call the desired function at the end of page load function ? Whenever the control comes to the server, page load will be invoked, thus calling your function. Doesn't require the button to be clicked for the function to be called.